# jquery select first child with class of a parent with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can i select only the first child of a particular class of a parent with a particular class for the purposes of `clone()`?

```
<div class="sector_order">

    <div class="line_item_wrapper">
    SELECT THIS DIV
    </div>

    <div class="line_item_wrapper">
    NOT THIS DIV
    </div>

</div>
```

I am trying like this:

```
var form1 = $(this)
    .parents('.sector_order')
    .children('.line_item_wrapper')
    .children().clone(true)
```

and get both inner divs with the class `line_item_wrapper`, but I get an empty object when I try with this addition:

```
children('.line_item_wrapper :first')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your problems is that your selector is wrong, in a few ways:

`parents()` returns one, two or many elements that match the selector passed to the method; to limit yourself to the first-matched element use `closest()` (which returns one, or no, elements that match the passed-in selector).

Your first use of the `children()` method returns both elements, since they *both* match the supplied selector and have the class of `line_item_wrapper`; you need to explicitly state which of the two you want, you can either use the `:first` selector (or the `first()` method), or the `:first-child` selector.

The second call to the `children()` method finds the children of the first element matched by the selector, which you don't *seem* to want.

Anyway, if you must use the parent (starting from the same `$(this)` element):

```
var form1 = $(this).closest('.sector_order').find('.line_item_wrapper:first').clone(true);
```

Or:

```
var form1 = $(this).closest('.sector_order').find('.line_item_wrapper').first().clone(true);
```

Or:

```
var form1 = $(this).closest('.sector_order').find('.line_item_wrapper:first-child').clone(true);
```

Or, frankly, a simpler approach (but this does dispense with the parent class-name check):

```
var form1 = $(this).prevAll('.line_item_wrapper:last');
```

Or:

```
var form1 = $(this).siblings('.line_item_wrapper').eq(0);
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).
- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this.

Answer (score 14):

You're passing an invalid selector to `children()`. 
Instead of

```
.children('.line_item_wrapper :first')
```

try

```
.children('.line_item_wrapper').first()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `:first-child`

```
var form1 = $(this).closest('.sector_order').find(':first-child');
```

OR `.first()`

```
var form1 = $(this).closest('.sector_order').find('.line_item_wrapper').first();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $firstDiv = $(".sector_order > .line_item_wrapper:eq(0)");
```

This will get you the first direct descendant of `sector_order` with the class `line_item_wrapper`.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2G4GY/)