# Make element the first child of it's parent list, on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a ul list with 4 list items in it. The list items have IDs named #one, #two, #three and #four:

```
  <ul class="home_slider">
    <li id="one">one</li>
    <li id="two">two</li>
    <li id="three">three</li>
    <li id="four">four</li>
  </ul>
```

There is also another ul list with 4 corresponding list items:

```
  <ul class="btn_wrap">
    <li class="btn" id="btn-01"></li>
    <li class="btn" id="btn-02"></li>
    <li class="btn" id="btn-03"></li>
    <li class="btn" id="btn-04"></li>
  </ul>
```

The four list items in the second ul list act as buttons using jQuery click.

The buttons correspond to the first ul list's items, for example #btn-01 manipulates #one.

**The question**

I want to make it so when you click on #btn-01, it makes #one become the first-child of its parent ul "home_slider".

Same logic applies to the other buttons, **so when you click #btn-02 it would make #two become the first child of "home_slider".**

Here is a JS Fiddle with comments where I imagine the code needs to go:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CultureInspired/gr5vg7m2/1/)

There is slightly more going on in the fiddle, such as classes being added on click, but for simplicity's sake, I left that out as it doesn't really pertain to the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406332/jquery-select-first-child-with-class-of-a-parent-with-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that will help you here, I [altered your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Ldymx7t/) as shown:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="home_slider">
  <li data-id="btn-01" id="one">one</li>
  <li data-id="btn-02" id="two">two</li>
  <li data-id="btn-03" id="three">three</li>
  <li data-id="btn-04" id="four">four</li>
</ul>

<ul class="btn_wrap">
  <li class="btn" id="btn-01"></li>
  <li class="btn" id="btn-02"></li>
  <li class="btn" id="btn-03"></li>
  <li class="btn" id="btn-04"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('.btn').click(function() {
  var target = '[data-id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]';
  $('.btn').removeClass('btn-selected');
  $(this).addClass('btn-selected');

  $(target).prependTo('.home_slider');

  $('.home_slider > li').removeClass('active');
  $(target).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use `remove()` and `prependTo()`.

For instance, this will remove `#four` and prepend it to the beginning of `.home_slider`:

`$('#four').remove().prependTo('.home_slider');`

Of course, do this in all four of your handlers.

Update: an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfmxe1m1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `prepend` method like [here in your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr5vg7m2/4/)

```
$('#id').parent().prepend($('#id'))
```

Comment: Is there similar method to do exactly this, but not limited to the first child? Such as targeting 3rd or 5th child as the new list position?

Comment: yes, before() and after() - these insert element before or after target elemen

Comment: Or insertBefore() and insertAfter() - insert target element before or after element which is an argument of these methods